# Tracking visits to categories with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are looking at implementing GA onto our site (we currently use WebTrends). On the website are lots of records that are placed within multiple subtopics - think of a news story that is tagged with Europe, Politics and Business.

We have 6 topics with about 70 subtopics spread across them.

What's the best way to track visits to these subtopics. So, for the example above we would need to count a view to that news story as a visit to Europe, a visit to Politics and a visit to Business.

Would we need a different event for each subtopic, that is then fired if the news story is in that subtopic, or can/should we do this with custom dimensions?

In webtrends we just have one tag that reports all subtopics separated by a semi-colon.

We are using Google Tag Manager, if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your are looking for [content grouping](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en) in Google Analytics. It does what the name says, it groups content pages into categories that you can view separately in your reports.

You can either assign a page to a content grouping via a piece of tracking code, or via the analytics interface (for example based on a pattern in the urls or page titles, or completly manually by entering urls).

Comment: Oooo, how did i miss that. You can also set up Content groups through Google Tag Manager. I'll look into that, at first this sounds perfect. 
Thanks

Comment: I guess you missed that because it's pretty new (it hasn't even been rolled out to all accounts I'm administrating). But it's really incredibly useful IMO.

Comment: I just looked into it and i don't think it's able to track multiple groups per page - just the one. So this would be good for a few other things that i'm currently tracking with custom dimensions (eg content types) but not for categories.
It looks like, unless i'm missing something, Events are the answer.